# Ravendb Select with a subquery returns full object rather than subquery items

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-3, ravendb

#### Exception

`Cannot deserialize JSON object into type 'System.String'.`

#### Controller

```
var products = session.Query<Package>().Select(m => new PackageViewModel() {
    Description = m.Description,
    Id = m.Id,
    Title = m.Title,
    Urls = m.Items.Select(g => g.Url).ToArray() //string[] Urls
});
```

When I changed `Urls` to an `object` and did the assignment `Urls` was set to the full value of `m.Items` rather than a list of Urls.

By changing the above to the following it works just fine.

```
var products = session.Query<Package>().ToList();

var viewModel = products.Select(m => new PackageViewModel() {
    Description = m.Description,
    Id = m.Id,
    Title = m.Title,
    Urls = m.Items.Select(g => g.Url).ToArray()
}).ToList();
```

**This really isn't a problem but I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong.**

#### Full StackTrace

```
[JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize JSON object into type 'System.String'.]
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:417
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:223
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueNonProperty(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:208
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IWrappedCollection wrappedList, JsonReader reader, String reference, JsonArrayContract contract) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:719
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.<>c__DisplayClass1.<CreateAndPopulateList>b__0(IList l, Boolean isTemporaryListReference) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:665
Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.CollectionUtils.CreateAndPopulateList(Type listType, Action`2 populateList) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Utilities\CollectionUtils.cs:544

Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateAndPopulateList(JsonReader reader, String reference, JsonArrayContract contract) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:653
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String reference) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:446
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:225
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueProperty(JsonReader reader, JsonProperty property, Object target, Boolean gottenCurrentValue, Object currentValue) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:198
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonReader reader, Object target) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:552
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, String id) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:1028
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateAndPopulateObject(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, String id) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:858
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:396
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:223

Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueNonProperty(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:208
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Serialization\JsonSerializerInternalReader.cs:120
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:421
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonSerializer.cs:413
Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation.DeserializedResult(RavenJObject result) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\SessionOperations\QueryOperation.cs:173
Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation.Deserialize(RavenJObject result) in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\SessionOperations\QueryOperation.cs:139
System.Linq.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext() +110
System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +327
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
Raven.Client.Document.SessionOperations.QueryOperation.Complete() in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\SessionOperations\QueryOperation.cs:111
Raven.Client.Document.AbstractDocumentQuery`2.GetEnumerator() in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\AbstractDocumentQuery.cs:551
Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryInspector`1.GetEnumerator() in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryInspector.cs:94
Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryInspector`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() in c:\Builds\raven\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryInspector.cs:99
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeEnumerable(IEnumerable enumerable, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +61
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +1380
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +194
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, StringBuilder output, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +26
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj, SerializationFormat serializationFormat) +74
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object obj) +6
Mvc.Areas.Api.Controllers.PackagesController.List() in PackagesController.cs:38
lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +96
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linq parser isn't smart enough to deal with this projection.
It can do simple projections, but nested stuff are quite complex, and aren't supported.
You can do that using the LuceneQuery API (the field to load is "Items,Url")